# MSBUILD used in from wrong location in VS2017 after uninstalling VS2015? XmlSerializers builds with incorrect versions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I uninstalled VS2017 and VS2015 and only re-installed VS2017.  Now, on some asp.net 3.5 assemblies that were previously building/working fine in VS2017 are no longer building correctly.

Even though the project references system.xml v2.0, when it is build, the *.XmlSerializers assembly pulls in the v4.0 version of the assembly.  Causing our sites running on the asp.net 2.0 application pool to no longer function.

Here is my assembly Application settings:

[image]

Here is my project reference:

[image]

And here is Ildasm.exe showing the wrong system.xml pulled in:

[image]

The only bindings I have in the web.config are the following:

[image]

I'm trying to determine if it is build MSBuild is ran from the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` path or what.

**UPDATE:** I ran a build with detailed output on my desktop (the one that no longer functions properly) and my laptop (which still works).  There were obviously lots of differences, but the ones that jumped out as possible issues are:

*Laptop (still working)*
SDK35ToolsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\
MSBuildVersion = 15.7.180
TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\
VSSDK140Install = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VSSDK\ **missing from desktop**
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.8.3.63029 (e9a3a6c0) (TaskId:28)

*Desktop (not working)*
SDK35ToolsPath =
MSBuildVersion = 15.9.21
TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.10.0.0 (b9fb1610) (TaskId:28)

Wonder if I should reinstall VS2015 again as well even though I'll never use the UI?

Comment: Have you checked your projects to see what version of the framework they are targeting?

Comment: @JuanR Yes, those have not changed.  Nothing in my projects have changed, but now all my builds pull in incorrect information into the XmlSerializer.dll's.  I've added image above showing my settings.

Comment: So.... what Framework are the projects supposed to be running under and what Framework is being targeted?

Comment: I know you mentioned "those have not changed". There is a chance something else changed it. That's why I ask.

Comment: Sites and assemblies are built targeting .NET Framework 3.5 and running in IIS under `managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0"`.

Comment: Any assembly redirects in the configuration files?

Comment: I assume you mean `assemblyBinding`?

Comment: Yes. Check this out too: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/668653/visual-studio-compiler-wrong-path-how-to-change.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187894/discussion-between-terry-and-juanr).

Comment: Sounds like VS2017 no longer installs .NET Framework 3.5 SDK by default. Go to VS2017 installer and select .NET Framework 3.5 development tools and you might get it working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from the comment.

VS2017/2019 no longer installs .NET Framework 3.5 SDK by default. That's why you saw `SDK35ToolsPath` is blank in MSBuild logging.

Go to VS2017/2019 installer and select .NET Framework 3.5 development tools to install. Then it should compile without problems.